# R: Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'-- raster data

Tags: r, plot, raster, r-raster

Im working in Studio with a raster `.tif` image. I have watched a tutorial on plotting the raster with the code below, however it does not work for me. I get the error:

> *Error in as.double(y) :    cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'*

I have loaded the necessary packages(`raster` and `rgdal`)
I have also tried loading the `arulesViz`, yet get the same error

```
YIELD <- raster("//Users//DevinOsborne//Desktop//Thesis//QGIS projects //Project//Rasters//Images//Yield_wheat.tif")

plot(YIELD,main= "Yield map")
```

Comment: whats the output when you write `YIELD` ? Do you get any error message when you tried to load the raster into R? It seems like the import failed.

Comment: try to change the `r version` in `tools` `global options` and restart `r studio`.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @Chelmy88 s answer, try `sp::plot()`
You will first need the `sp` package; `install.packages("sp")`

I was able to recreate your error with `graphics::plot()`

I believe that when you load `raster` library `sp` will also be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue while using `rgdal` in a custome R package.
This error as been solved for me by loading the `sp` library. The problem was not arising when running the script alone, but once included in the package I had the same error when using `plot()`:

> Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type
>   'double'

This has been solved by adding `import("sp")` in the NAMESPACE file and "sp" to the Import list in the DESCRIPTION file.

Unfortunately I could not find which `sp` function is required, so I use a full import instead of a more targeted `importFrom()` in the NAMESPACE file.