# R Biogeo pkg: Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r

I am usually pretty good at figuring out error messages as long as it doesn't require much looking at the underlying code, but I am very new to working with spatial data, and can't figure this one out.

I am using the **Biogeo package** with RStudio v. 0.99.903, R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10), Windows 10 (EDIT: upgrade to newest version of R did not get rid of the error). **I am currently working through the tutorial** alongside trying to apply it to my own data. The function code and relevant data are on github at: **https://github.com/cran/biogeo** (the tutorial narrative is in the docs folder - I am at the beginning, trying to make the map on page 2).

I am getting the following error when using the **pointsworld function**:

```
Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

Related questions I found on Stack Overflow (one unanswered, one I don't really understand):

(1) [R: Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'-- raster data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911076/rstudio-error-in-as-doubley-cannot-coerce-type-s4-to-vector-of-type-doub)
(2) [Self-authored package: load plot method for spatialPolygonsDataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818682/self-authored-package-load-plot-method-for-spatialpolygonsdataframe)

This is my relevant code (from the tutorial):

```
library(biogeo)
data(dat) # Access the species dataset
data(world) # Access the country boundaries
a <- pointsworld(world, dat) # basic plotting
```

I also tried the function with a subset of my own data, and received the same error.

These are all of the packages I currently have open:

```
search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:dplyr"     "package:maptools"      "package:biogeo"    "package:raster"
[6] "package:sp"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
[11] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

`typeof()` returns `"S4"` for "world" and `"list"` for dat

`class()` returns `"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" attr(,"package") "sp"` for "world" and `"data.frame"` for "dat"

I hope I have not overlooked something simple - I have typed and retyped the code, tried it with different data sets, tried it with the suggested (in the tutorial) map/boundaries file from ...www.thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php (take off the dots at the start, I don't have enough reputation pts to post the link), and have tried directly copy and pasting directly from the tutorial the different examples of using this function.

Hopefully it is not just a result of me not drinking enough coffee yet - I've spent much time trying to figure this out, and am hoping somebody here can help.

Thanks!
Liz

Comment: UPDATE: I just tried with a fresh R session, and still get the same error. Here is session info:

Comment: R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
(to be continued)

Comment: attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] biogeo_1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7     lattice_0.20-33 permute_0.9-4   MASS_7.3-45     grid_3.3.1     
 [6] nlme_3.1-128    magrittr_1.5    stringi_1.1.2   raster_2.5-8    vegan_2.4-1    
[11] sp_1.2-3        Matrix_1.2-6    tools_3.3.1     stringr_1.1.0   foreign_0.8-66 
[16] parallel_3.3.1  cluster_2.0.4   maptools_0.8-39 mgcv_1.8-15

Comment: UPDATE: I am now completely out of ideas... I just tried the tutorial code, as is, from the R console, and get the same result.

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to plot, try library(sp) to attach sp's plotting methods.

Comment: @mdsumner, I just tried that, and it didn't work. I think sp was already loaded, because when I ran 'library(sp)', there was no output indicating it was attaching. The session info indicates that biogeo loads sp. Nonetheless, I tried running all of the instances of the 'pointsworld' function in the tutorial after running 'library(sp)', and received the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though, I'm fresh out of ideas, and willing to try anything. :-)

Comment: I emailed the package author late last night with a link to this post - hopefully he will respond if there is not a solution by the time he sees this. I'm wondering if it  has something to do with the recent update in R, with the corresponding updates to packages that biogeo depends on...

Comment: I used 'spplot' to plot the world data (without my points), and that worked, so I am guessing that the biogeo function, 'pointsworld', modifies the 'spplot' function to allow the addition of points from a nonspatial dataframe? Is it possible an update to the sp package changed the way that would be handled, resulting in broken code in the biogeo 'pointsworld' function? Sorry if this is a dumb question - I'm completely new to dealing with spatial data, so I am finding it difficult to imagine what the pointsworld function is doing with the two sets of data.

Comment: In case anybody is interested in looking at the code for the functions to see if the problem is there, this might be helpful. I get the same error in section 5.2 (p8) of the tutorial with the function 'alternatives'. Here are the comments and code from the tutorial:

Comment: # 5.2. Get alternative coordinates using geographical visualization
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# View alternative coordinates for a selected record. For all species
d3 <- alternatives(dat,group1="Species",group2="",world,dem,locality="LocalityName",pos="bottomleft",ext="p")

Comment: Calling `traceback()` after the `pointsworld(world, dat)`, it appears that the appropriate `plot` method is not triggered since `plot.default` is called in the line inside `pointsworld` containing `plot(world, ...etc)`.  I guess the call at that line should behave like `sp::plot(world)` does -- "biogeo" package might not have been connected appropriately to its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @alexis_laz for taking a look at the code. It makes sense to me what you are saying, but I don't know how to connect a package to its dependencies, so I will have to wait to hear back from the author I guess. :-(  I wouldn't care so much, except there is a function later that returns the same error, which lends support to your suggestion that the dependencies are not connected appropriately. Thanks!

Comment: Investigating @alexis_laz's idea and will report back, and mark as answered if this is the issue. Could be a while, as this is new territory for me, but I'm too impatient, and hate feeling helpless, haha.

Comment: @Liz : Didn't look at it extensively, but [this chapter](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Namespaces-with-S4-classes-and-methods) might be relevant -- i.e. there could be a `importMethodsFrom("sp", "plot")` or something similar from `biogeo`'s NAMESPACE

Comment: It's definitely biogeo's problem. Why it needs to have a function that separates a SpatialPointsDataFrame into x = geometry(spdf), y = as.data.frame(spdf) is unclear. It also refers to "x" as a "shapefile", which it is not.

Comment: I don't see any point to this function, just use plot(world); points(coordinates(world)) and otherwise ask here about general use of the sp family for making maps.

Comment: @mdsummer, you are correct, there are easier ways to do this particular task. However, the package has another function (alternativesenv) that returns the same error, likely for the same reason. I think I have figured it out, but had to stop working yesterday as I was just about there, and just got back to it today. I think that alexis_laz had the right idea. I should know within the hour.

Comment: Many thanks to each of you!  Except for a CRS issue, I got the function working, and it was all of your comments that finally got me going in the right direction, especially @alexis_laz who got me looking in the namespace and the description. Quick summary in next message.

Comment: In lines 18-19, I put quotes around the x and y, and also specified that the match function should be from the base package. in lines 37-40 I specified that the functions should be from the sp package. When going through the function line by line, I kept getting an error telling me the function could not be found, so there appears to be something wrong with how the sp functions are being imported (??). I will mark this as solved, even though importing the sp functions is the real issue, but I can't see anything wrong in the namespace or description, so I don't know how to fix at the moment.

Comment: oops, forgot I wasn't looking at my own data, there is no CRS mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

line numbers refer to code at https://github.com/cran/biogeo/blob/master/R/pointsworld.R

In lines 37-40 I specified that the functions should be from the sp package (e.g., `sp::spatialPoints`). Contrary to my previous comment, nothing had to be changed in previous lines. There appears to be something wrong with how the sp functions are being imported (??). I am marking this as answered, even though importing the sp functions is the real issue, but I'm not sure how to fix that at the moment (just need to learn though!).

Comment: I have let the package author know about the issues. In the meantime, if anybody is trying to use this package and having problems, here is what I did to get it to work (no problems so far, will update if necessary):

Comment: [continued from previous comment]  (1) downloaded & used untar to unzip biogeo tar file from cran, (2) located functions with the following internal functions and made the indicated changes to specify package to use: `plot` --> `sp::plot` , `CRS` --> `sp::CRS` , `over` --> `sp::over`' , `SpatialPoints` --> `sp::SpatialPoints` , `extract` --> `raster::extract` . **Probably not the most efficient solution, but it works**

Comment: Forgot to add toend of my last comment: after making the changes above, I (1) uninstalled the original version of the biogeo package, (2) used the `tar` function to zip up the copy of the biogeo files that included the edited function files, and saved it as 'biogeo.tar.gz', and (3) installed my local edited copy of biogeo with the `devtools::install` function.